# Upgrading OAuth2/OpenID2 to OpenID Connect

Tags: asp.net, dotnetopenauth, google-openid, openid-connect

I'm using DotNetOpenAuth library for managing authentication.
Now google has decided to not support anymore OpenId2, I've read the documentation but I haven't understood very well how I can migrate to OpenId Connect.

Now I'm authenticating with google sending the following request:

```
        using(OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty())
        {
            string googleEndPoint = "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id";
            IAuthenticationRequest request = openid.CreateRequest(Identifier.Parse(googleEndPoint));
            ...
```

So I'm wondering if I have to modify only openid.CreateRequest(Identifier.Parse(googleEndPoint)) to include **REALM** and **Return URI** to make it work.

I'm looking for example on internet about Google auth with DotNetOpenAuth lib but I haven't found anything

Comment: it seems that DotNetOpenAuth doesn't support at all the new authentication by Google, and another lib must be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. For migrating to OIDC Google recommends to use the "HD" parameter, see details here:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#openid-connect

I recently created a lightweight implementation of authentication against Google OIDC and made this library open source. The code is pretty basic and gets the job done:

http://www.dominikamon.com/articles/3091/oidc-lightweight-library-for-aspnet.html

The new API works different if you want to access information such as firstname, lastname, gender. You need to get this information from Google+. Therefore you need  need to setup the Google+ API (You can send up to 10000 requests per day for free)

Hope this helps.